# How to make \captionof have: 1) more space between image and caption & 2) encompass less width than \textwidth

Tags: graphics, captions

This question is specifically regarding `\captionof`s, which I have been using instead of `captions`s since the latter are floating.

(Unfortunately, I have experienced that `\captionof`'s sometimes interfere with something simple as an `abstract`, which I thus had to remove.)

Regarding the lay-out of `\captionof`s:

1. I would like to have the `\captionof` encompass less width than the `\textwidth`.

   Already, I obtained this using:

   ```
   \parbox{0.9\linewidth}{\captionof{figure}{
   ```

   But, I inserted the desire into the question anyway, because there might be a more elegant way to solve both questions.
2. Now, I would like to increase space between the vertical space between the caption and the image (but specifically for `\captionof`s, instead of normal `\caption`s -> I have not been able to achieve this considering other similar questions for `\caption`s).

Comment: `\captionof` just calls `\caption` so _all_ formatting of `\captionof` is defined from `\caption`. the entire capt-of package is `\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}`

Comment: I don't understand this question. The output of `\captionof` looks the same for me

Comment: My apologies. I have been encountering too many incompatibility issues, and am seeing too many different back-up versions at once, which must have confused me, I guess. But I have sincerely problems when I insert an `abstract`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical distance between `\caption` and the image (or whatever) can be controlled with `\captionsetup{skip=...}` where `...` stands for some appropiate value. The standard value for `article`, `report` and `book` is `10pt`.

Please note that the `caption` manual clearly states that still the `class` or another package might take control of the skip between figure or table content (the figure/table etc. environments are defined by the class, not by `caption`. `skip=` actually sets `\abovecaptionskip`, a LaTeX length register. Changing `\belowcaptionskip` could help too.

For the margins, the `minmargin=...` and `maxmargin=...` option keys can be used, see the example and the screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\fakeverb}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\begin{document}


\captionsetup{skip=5pt}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente.jpg}}
  \hrule
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
  \caption{Caption with \fakeverb{caption} for this very nice image of a cute duck}
\end{figure}

{
  \centering

  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente.jpg}}
  \hrule
  \captionof{figure}{Caption with \fakeverb{captionof} for this very nice image of a cute duck}
}

\clearpage

\captionsetup{skip=2pt, minmargin=3cm, maxmargin=3cm}
{
  \centering

  \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente.jpg}}
  \hrule
  \captionof{figure}[Too long for LoF]{\fakeverb{captionof} with a long text: \blindtext}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems more to control the vertical distance after `\caption`, rather than the distance between `\caption` and the `image`?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen: It will not always work, as the manual (reading helps ;-)) clearly states